# How to save value on a drop down to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im just new in programming and im creating  a simple drop down using html where you can choose  what pet you are looking for/ Options are DOG, CAT, FISH and Others. if you choose others a text box will show so you can fill it up if the pet you looking for is not in the list.
My problem is that if i choose the an option on the drop down it doesn't save on the database but it shows blank and if i choose others and fill out the text box it will  be saved on the database

codes that i did is here .. hope you can help

```
 <select name="lookingfor" onchange='CheckInfo(this.value);' > 
<option>What your looking for?</option>  
<option value="DOG">DOG</option>
<option value="CAT">CAT</option>
<option value="FISH">FISH</option>
<option value="others">Others</option>
```

```
   <input type="text" name="lookingfor" id="lookingfor" style='display:none;' placeholder="What kind of pet ?" class="lookingfor"/>
```

for PHP to save to the database is here..

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("****","****","c****","****");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO injectinfo (lookingfor)
   VALUES ('$_POST[lookingfor]')");

   mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: first make sure **$_POST[lookingfor]** you are getting the lookingfor value?

Comment: give unique name to both the controls dropdown box and textbox

Comment: try to echo $_POST[lookingfor]; and see, it always work

Answer (score 1):

in the query you should put `{$_POST['lookingfor']}` instead of `$_POST[lookingfor]`

it would look like this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO injectinfo (lookingfor) VALUES ('{$_POST['lookingfor']}')");
```

or you can make it like this:

```
$temp = $_POST['lookingfor'];
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO injectinfo (lookingfor) VALUES ('$temp')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this query instead of your query

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO injectinfo (lookingfor)
       VALUES ($_POST['lookingfor'])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value from the Label ID and assign to the variable and use that in class file..

```
$RollNumber=$_REQUEST['#RollNumber'];
```